# Web3.py transfer call failing, not sure why

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, python

I am trying to learn how to work with ethereum and ERC20 tokens. I have managed to setup ganache and deploy my contract. I can see it on ganache and I can connect and read the balance of the token on the contract with no problems. I am moving onto making transactions for the token.

Below is the code I am trying to use.

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))

# Load contract
ABI_PATH="myabifile.json"
truffleFile = json.load(open(ABI_PATH))
contract = w3.eth.contract("0xE6b7aD1717AD978d4Cf573FD750863B16c362890", abi=truffleFile["abi"])

# Set default account
w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]

make a transfer with an address on the network
tx_hash = contract.functions.transfer("0x5eB642aD40467499783868EAd82F41cf0730f6e4", 10).transact()
```

I keep getting the following error ...

```
{'message': 'execution error: revert', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'Error: execution error: revert\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/gasEstimation.js:12:11\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/dist/runTx.js:74:9\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5225:18)\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/dist/state/cache.js:160:13\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/util.js:51:36\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16\n    at done (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17)\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/database/levelupobjectadapter.js:110:7\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16\n    at iteratorCallback (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1064:13)\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/level-sublevel/shell.js:53:51\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/level-sublevel/nut.js:109:13\n    at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/database/filedown.js:64:7', 'name': 'Error'}}
```

I see it has something to do with gasEstimation, but I can't figure out what I am doing incorrect.

I have been following a few tutorials, this one is the one I have been following for this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5W67zTQFRM&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgVn38FOhXvLc0PoX_0hnJO9&index=4

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.